# Building a dynamic anonymous type Select statement using Linq

Tags: linq, dynamic-linq

```
//list is IEnumeable NOT IEnumerable<T>

var IEnumerable<object> = list.AsQueryable().Cast<object>().Select(x=> .........);
```

object actually has a POCO underlying Anonymous class e.g

```
AccountId,Name,SecretInfo
```

What I want in the select statement is

```
AccountId = x.GetType().GetProperty("AccountId").GetValue(x,null),
Name = x.GetType().GetProperty("Name").GetValue(x,null)
```

Also I want to hide the SecretInfo Column which I can pass as a hardcoded string "SecretInfo"
Basically the select list needs to be built up dynamically on the Anonymous type....
How can this be done....Any Linq punters out there who can help me?

Comment: Are you aware that an anonymous class is still strongly-typed? And why is list IEnumerable and not IEnumerable<T>?

Comment: I'm using IEnumerable because its generic and I can't change it <T>

Comment: What's your datasource, which makes that impossible? I barely can imagine cases where strong typing is not possible (besides Interop)

Comment: It is a generic framework hence I can't do anything about it. I just need the select list maybe using reflection ??

Comment: Okay - there will be some class, which has the data in the your generic framework (by the way it's very helpfull for the helpers to get some not so abstract information - but that's for the future only), which you probably could use - you could look into the type with an debugger and then cast to the correct type.

Nevertheless you can also cast to dynamic:
`list.Select(x => ((dynamic)x).AccountId)` But this is really not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question relies on [anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx). The following code is what you can use:

```
var result = list.AsQueryable().Cast<Info>().Select(x => new
    {
        AccountId = x.AccountId,
        Name = x.Name
    });
```

Between the brackets that follow the new keyword in the select statement, you are creating an anonymous type that will have two implicitly typed read-only fields (AccountId and Name). Hope this helps!

I would like to post this quote from the linked (no pun intended) article:

> Anonymous types typically are used in the select clause of a query expression to return a subset of the properties from each object in the source sequence. For more information about queries, see [LINQ Query Expressions (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397676.aspx).

Comment: Why the downvote? Everything I posted is true and applicable.